# Spyder pdb debugger: (!) special character

Tags: python, debugging, spyder, pdb

Python's Spyder IDE, v.2.3, offers debugging mode using the pdb library: https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/debugging.html

Looking at that library's documentation, section 26.3 states:

"Commands that the debugger doesn’t recognize are assumed to be Python statements and are executed in the context of the program being debugged. Python statements can also be prefixed with an exclamation point (!)."

https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html#debugger-commands

However, when using the special character ! in Spyder's pdb session, the following error appears:

(Pdb) !b

(Pdb) 'b' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

THE PROBLEM appears to be that in Spyder's pdb prefixing "!" does not work as intended. This appears to be a bug.

Thanks

Comment: b is not normally a python command.  Try `!print b` if you have a variable called `b`.

Comment: Thanks Steve. However, prefixing a statement with "!" does not appear to work in Spyder's Pdb (it works in the standard pdb). 

"!print b" generates an error "Unable to initialize device PRN".

Comment: Bug acknowledged: https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=2146

Until it is fixed, developers recommend using IPython console to do debug.

Comment: Sorry for the inconveniences @JohnNapier, we'll fix this error in 2.3.4 :-)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a good bug report but now obsolete.